# Signed cookie does not let me set specific resources in the policy

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, signed

In S3, we create one bucket that contains multiple organizations. For the example above, we have the following device folder objects created. Again, User A should only access device1, device2 , but not device3.

https://s3.host/bucket/org1/devices/device1

https://s3.host/bucket/org1/devices/device2

https://s3.host/bucket/org1/devices/device3

We are using signed cookies to allow our browser application to access the S3 objects (per your documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-setting-signed-cookie-custom-policy.html)

The signed cookie however does not let me set specific resources in the policy and instead I would need a wild card policy. This creates a problem because the signed cookie allows access to device3.

s3://duclo.domain/bucket/org1/* <-- DOESN'T MEET

I am unable to set it to the following:

{ "Statement": [ { "Resource": " https://s3.host/bucket/org1/devices/device1", "Condition": { "IpAddress": { "AWS:SourceIp": "1.2.3.4" } } }, { "Resource": " https://s3.host/bucket/org1/devices/device2", "Condition": { "IpAddress": { "AWS:SourceIp": "1.2.3.4" } } } ] }

Instead, I can only do this below which again breaks the requirement.

{ "Statement": [ { "Resource": " https://s3.host/bucket/org1/devices/*", "Condition": { "IpAddress": { "AWS:SourceIp": "1.2.3.4" } } } ] }

I need it to allow multiple resources, or another solution perhaps?Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?